# EF Core - Mapping entities to custom classes throws stackoverflow for cyclic references

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, design-patterns, entity-framework-core

I'm building an API POC with asp.net core webapi. I'm trying to separate the EF Core entities from the objects returned by the API so I can customise them for different methods.

To achieve this I've created custom classes to which I map the entities. This breaks down when I'm trying to map Entities having one-to-many or many-to-many relations (2x one-to-many with an intermediary entity in EF Core)

EF Core Entities

```cs
public class Country
{
  [Key]
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  // Relations
  public virtual ICollection<CountryRegion> CountryRegions { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Region
{
  [Key]
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  // Relations
  public virtual ICollection<CountryRegion> CountryRegions { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class CountryRegion
{
  public string CountryCode { get; set; }
  public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

  public string RegionCode { get; set; }
  public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

API-side custom class example for mapping the Country entity

```cs
public class Country
{
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
  public IList<CountryRegion> Regions { get; set; }

  public Country() { }

  public Country(Database.Models.Country country)
  {
    this.Code = country.Code;
    this.Name = country.Name;

    if (country.CountryRegions != null)
    {
      this.Regions = country.CountryRegions.Select(cr => new CountryRegion(cr.Region)).ToList();
    }
  }

  public static implicit operator Country(Database.Models.Country country)
  {
    return country != null ? new Country(country) : null;
  }
}
```

Included CountryRegion from the API side as suggested by Ivan Stoev. Building my class like this solves the problem, however I have to create an extra class on each side of the relation (RegionCountry on the region side, which maps the country). What I'm trying to do is avoid this in cases like "A country has many users. A user has a country." I'd have to make a Country class that has the Users collection and one that doesn't to be able to map it on both the User and Country side when intuitively the two classes themselves should be enough... if this makes sense?

```cs
public class CountryRegion
{
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public CountryRegion() { }

  public CountryRegion(Database.Models.Region region)
  {
    this.Code = region.Code;
    this.Name = region.Name;
  }

  public static implicit operator CountryRegion(Database.Models.Region region)
  {
    return region != null ? new CountryRegion(region) : null;
  }
}
```

Everything works fine EF-wise, but evidently, when executing this mapping, EF entities will just cycle through the relation and end up throwing a `StackOverflowException`.

I am almost convinced I am approaching this the wrong way. Is there maybe a pattern that already solves this issue that I've overlooked?

Comment: The problem seems to be in `CountryRegion` class used here `new CountryRegion(cr.Region)`, so please include it in the post.

Comment: @IvanStoev I've added the class with a bit of extra context of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Here `this.Regions = country.CountryRegions.Select(cr => new CountryRegion(cr.Region)).ToList();` how are you able to assign a `List<CountryRegion>` to a `IList<Region>`

Comment: @gkb sorry, I made that edit for the sake of the post, it's suppose to be `IList<CountryRegion>`. Made an edit

Comment: So this is not the problematic class. When asking a question, It will be good if you provide the code which reproduces the problem. Anyway, in order to support cyclic references, the mapping code should receive some additional parameter - mapping context, at minimum something like `Dictionary<object, object>` which maintains the already mapped objects. Similar to any graph processing algorithm which needs to mark the already "visited" nodes. EF for sure uses something like that internally.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to work around needing satellite classes to cast each end of the relation by just removing the cyclic reference. This works, but I still feel this is kind of awkward and asked the question more from a design pattern point of view, maybe there's a more elegant way to do this?

```cs
public class Country
{
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
  public IList<Region> Regions { get; set; }

  public Country() { }

  public Country(Database.Models.Country country)
  {
    this.Code = country.Code;
    this.Name = country.Name;

    if (country.CountryRegions != null)
    {
      this.Regions = country.CountryRegions
        .Select(cr => { cr.Region.CountryRegions = null; return new Region(cr.Region); })
        .ToList();
    }
  }

  public static explicit operator Country(Database.Models.Country country)
  {
    return country != null ? new Country(country) : null;
  }
}
```

```cs
public class Region
{
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
  public IList<Country> Countries { get; set; }

  public Region() { }

  public Region(Database.Models.Region region)
  {
    this.Code = region.Code;
    this.Name = region.Name;

    if (region.CountryRegions != null)
    {
      this.Countries = region.CountryRegions
        .Select(cr => { cr.Country.CountryRegions = null; return new Country(cr.Country); })
        .ToList();
    }
  }

  public static explicit operator Region(Database.Models.Region region)
  {
    return region != null ? new Region(region) : null;
  }
}
```